# Nginx automatically add trailing slash before query string

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I connect to:
`http://localhost/api?foo=bar`

Nginx redirect me to:
`http://localhost/api/?foo=bar`

Therefore, my backed do not respond correctly.

I have tried change location to `location /api` then problem solved but it also match something like `http://localhost/apiapi?foo=bar` and I don't want that.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `location = /api { ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks! It worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the URI `/api` to access your service.

The `location /api/` does not match that API unless an additional `/` is added (which Nginx is automatically appending via a redirect).

The `location /api` also matches any URI that begins with the same three characters.

As your service only needs to respond to the single URI, you can use an exact match `location`.

For example:

```
location = /api {
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.